# How to get ink level of network printer in java

Tags: java, swing, printing

I'm trying to find a way to get the ink level of a printer in java.

My task is to:

- Get info from the network printer
- Getting the ink level property from that printer info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any generic solution exists for this. Only the printer driver can report the details like the ink level. Either find out the driver details and driver API for talking to printer OR use printer's wire protocol to talk to it for querying the ink level.

Comment: Ya you are right.But the same i need to do using java programming.